# Google Spreadsheet Scripting - Get getColumn of single referenced cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I want have a function in which I pass a single referenced cell, not a range, and it returns the column number of that cell.

```js
function lastRealDate(v) {
  var thisColumn = v.getColumn();
  return thisColumn;
}​
```

But apparently I can not do it like that.  Can anyone show me the right way?  Very new to scripting for spreadsheets.

```
error: TypeError: Cannot find function getColumn in object
```

---

Ok, maybe I should give more detail.
I have a list of jobs each with the following columns..

Project Name | Status | Completion Date | Days Left
Job #1 | Ready | 12/5/12 | 0.14 
Job #2 | HOLD | 12/5/12 | 0.25 
Job #3 | Ready | 12/6/12 | 1.0

Completion date is calculated by...

if(Days Left > 0, WORKDAY(Previous Project's Completion Date, Days Left)
which is literally: =if(J5>0,WORKDAY(G4,J5,vars!$A$2:$A$27),"")

This all works fine.  But now I want to check the status column.  If the prior job's status is on hold, then i want to skip that one and check the next one prior.

So basically I needed to loop through the cells until I find the next job that is not on HOLD and grab that Completion Date.

I was thinking something like this:

=if(J5>0,WORKDAY(custom_function(G4),J5,vars!$A$2:$A$27),"")

Any thoughts on that scenario?

Comment: This should not happen, if a range(/cell) is passed into your function.  Perhaps you should post the calling code (including the code that gets the cell/range).

Comment: @Brian I'm assuming he is using this as a custom function. If you're not, then you really need to paste the rest of the code.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu oh, huh.  I didn't even think of a function called explicitly from the spreadsheet.  Good thought.

Comment: I updated my description to include more detail.  For what I was trying to accomplish, I just figured using a script would be best, but I didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that is not possible. You can not write "meta" custom functions.
The parameter `v` passed to your function, regardless if it's just one cell, one row or column or the whole sheet are always going to be the values of the cells, not their "reference" or a range object.

The good thing is that you already have built-in functions to do that, e.g. `=COLUMN(C1)`. And whenever you have a built-in function alternative to a custom one you should use the built-in. Well, I'd go further and say: never use custom functions. If you do need a script to make a calculation, use an another way of calling, i.e. custom menus, image "buttons", `onEdit` trigger and so on. Specially now that you're learning, avoid custom function at all. They are not worth it.

Comment: It is true that there are examples of custom functions on the fora that can and should be achieved with native functions. However, I'm not sure I agree that "all custom functions are bad" Henrique. I have several custom functions that work flawlessly, that would otherwise require a ridiculously convoluted native formula that is difficult to maintain.

Comment: I should make a dossier to explain and base my campaign against custom functions. But you know they are tough to work with (correctly) and have very, very limited usage. And you? You're legendary Adam! You have SS convoluted formulas for breakfast :)

Comment: I updated my description to include more detail.  I definitely try to use built-in functions when possible.  I just thought this scenario called for more.

Comment: @Henrique : you have it for lunch... just a matter of personal taste ;-)  AFAIAC my stomach can't handle them... sorry

Comment: Haha +Henrique, being able to do complicated spreadsheet formulae is "legendary-lite", you coders deserve way more respect. And I've broken several ss (mine and others :-( ) with a complicated ss formula, where a "pure" custom function (JS only) has worked well. Probably goes without saying but I never write custom functions that aren't "pure" (use GAS services, spreadsheet gets etc).

Answer (score 1):

+Henrique has answered your general question about what information is passed to a custom function.

---

In answer to the particular use case in your edit, a formula with native functions might be (assuming the dates in column G are in ascending order, and status is column F):

`=IF(J5>0;WORKDAY(MAX(FILTER(G$2:G4;F$2:F4<>"HOLD"));J5;vars!$A$2:$A$27);"")`